# How to fix "'User' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, json, gitlab

I am trying to write some Python code, that gets the users Gitlab Profile picture/avatar to be sent in a Discord Embed later on in the code. However, when i try to read the json that the Gitlab API returns but i receive the error "'User' object is not subscriptable" this json doesnt look like other jsons returned by the Gitlab API.

I have tried to use Attributes but i still receive the same error, i have also tried just to read it but i still receive the same error.

```py
import gitlab
import json

# private token or personal token authentication
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('URL', private_token='')

project = gl.projects.get(13)
json_data = project.tags.list(order_by='updated', sort='desc')
newest_tagjson = (json_data[0].attributes)
latesttag = newest_tagjson["name"]
name1 = newest_tagjson["commit"]["author_name"]
projectid = newest_tagjson["project_id"]
footer1 = "Panel"
if name1 == "------":
    ID = 16
user = gl.users.get(ID)
print(user)
user2 = (user['avatar_url'].attributes)
```

i should receive a clean json that i can read but instead i recieve this in the print

```
<class 'gitlab.v4.objects.User'> => {'id': 16, 'name': '', 'username': '', 'state': 'active', 'avatar_url': 'https://URL.io/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/16/avatar.png', 'web_url': '', 'created_at': '2019-01-29T18:30:53.819Z', 'bio': ' \r\n', 'location': ', United Kingdom', 'public_email': '', 'skype': '', 'linkedin': '', 'twitter': '', 'website_url': '', 'organization': ''}
```

and i cannot read this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear: the result of calling `gl.users.get(ID)` is not a Python dictionary, so you can't access keys with subscripts as in `user['avatar_url']`.  You can access attributes using Python's dot notation, as in `user.avatar_url`.

You can of course extract the information you want into a Python dictionary:

```py
>>> user_dict = {k: getattr(user, k) for k in
... ['id', 'name', 'state', 'avatar_url', 'web_url']}
>>> user_dict
{'id': 28841, 'name': 'Lars Kellogg-Stedman', 'state': 'active', 'avatar_url': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1c09a8d9e719f9d13b6c99f6bb2637d8?s=80&d=identicon', 'web_url': 'https://gitlab.com/larsks'}
```

And then you can serialize this to JSON:

```py
>>> print(json.dumps(user_dict, indent=2))
{
  "id": 28841,
  "name": "Lars Kellogg-Stedman",
  "state": "active",
  "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1c09a8d9e719f9d13b6c99f6bb2637d8?s=80&d=identicon",
  "web_url": "https://gitlab.com/larsks"
}
```

The Python `gitlab` module wraps the gitlab API in a variety of managers designed to make certain things easier, but if your goal is to serialize things to JSON it might be easier to simply call the REST API yourself:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> session.headers['private-token'] = your_private_token
>>> res = session.get('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/28841')
>>> res.json()
{'id': 28841, 'name': 'Lars Kellogg-Stedman', 'username': 'larsks', 'state': 'active', 'avatar_url': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1c09a8d9e719f9d13b6c99f6bb2637d8?s=80&d=identicon', 'web_url': 'https://gitlab.com/larsks', 'created_at': '2014-04-26T01:52:14.000Z', 'bio': '', 'location': None, 'public_email': '', 'skype': '', 'linkedin': '', 'twitter': 'larsks', 'website_url': 'http://blog.oddbit.com/', 'organization': None}
```